# sql query not working in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

This returns results:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id LIKE :id ORDER BY id');
$query->bindValue(':id', $this->id.'_');
```

This does not:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT g.*, d.desc_text FROM groups g LEFT JOIN descriptions d ON d.desc_id=g.id WHERE g.id LIKE :id AND d.desc_type=1 ORDER BY g.id');
$query->bindValue(':id', $this->id.'_');
```

And yet if I run the SQL query below in WebMin ("0002_" is the value being bound in the above), then I get results.

```
SELECT g.*, d.desc_text FROM groups g LEFT JOIN descriptions d ON d.desc_id=g.id WHERE g.id LIKE "0002_" AND d.desc_type=1 ORDER BY g.id
```

So why does the PDO dislike the query in my second piece of code above?

Comment: what is the datatype of id in the database?

Comment: @echo_me: no, there are no exceptions being generated.

Comment: @voncox: both g.id and d.desc_id are char(5) and the ids have the preceding zeros e.g. "0002A", "0002B", etc

Comment: try to remove "AND d.desc_type=1" from your query and check the result again. then check description column in result set.

Comment: @Boynux: I tried that, and it works; I got results with desc_text data included.  However I can't leave it like that because the descriptions table is used for various desc_types.  desc_type=1 is for product groups and has values such as "0002A", "0002B", etc,  However there are also page descriptions (desc_type=0) with ids like "0002 ", and product descriptions (desc_type=3) with ids like "00023",  obviously I don't want page or product descriptions being returned when I'm looking for group descriptions.  I need the desc_type somewhere in the SQL query.

Comment: I understand I just wanted to check that desc_type returns correct result ( I mean 1 here ), so in next step try to include desc_type in you select columns and check the result. is it realy '1'?

Comment: @Boynux: I found the solution to this but this site won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours (because I don't have a high enough ranking).  I'll post a proper answer, for the benefit of others, when it lets me... but in a nutshell: the "AND d.desc_type=1" needs to be part of the LEFT JOIN ON clause rather than the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answee, but it is still sounds odd to me, actually there should be no deference between the two in your query, would you please tell me how many records each group id has in descriptions table? and what is mysql and php version and also what engine do you use. i would like to create a sampke database myself to see the resut. it is very interesting to me. actually it seems to be a bug.

Comment: @Boynux: The query I've posted should return only one row, however it could return up to 26.  Product page ids are a 4 digit code (left padded with zeros).  Product groups on each page add a letter (A to Z) to then end of that code.  This query is intended to return all groups on the page;  The server is a LAMP server with PHP Version 5.1.6 and MySQL version 5.0.22.  Let me know if you need anything else.  I'll post a proper answer (so folks don't have to read all of these comments) when this system will let me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I nailed it:

As I said in my initial question, the code below doesn't return results:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT g.*, d.desc_text FROM groups g LEFT JOIN descriptions d ON d.desc_id=g.id WHERE g.id LIKE :id AND d.desc_type=1 ORDER BY g.id');
$query->bindValue(':id', $this->id.'_');
```

This code returns the expected results:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT g.*, d.desc_text FROM groups g LEFT JOIN descriptions d ON d.desc_id=g.id AND d.desc_type=1 WHERE g.id LIKE :id ORDER BY g.id');
$query->bindValue(':id', $this->id.'_');
```

Strangely, either SQL query will return results when run from within Webmin, but it seems that the PHP PDO doesn't like having the "AND d.desc_type=1" as part of the WHERE clause and needs it in the LEFT JOIN ON clause.

Answer (score -1):

> why does the PDO dislike the query in my second piece of code above?

Ask PDO:

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

If PDO doesn't throw any errors - it "likes" your query and **has nothing to do with the problem.** Check your data, database and typos.

As a final check omit bindvalue part

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('put your query from WEBMIN here');
$stmt->execute();
$res  = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($res);
```

if it retirns any data - blame PDO
if not - check your data, database and typos.

Comment: Already in place and I put the code within a try/catch so it would show me any errors generated: there are none.

Comment: I've checked and rechecked the data, database and for typos, but I'm not seeing anything problematic (my code examples are copied and pasted).  I think that I got results when I ran the query in Webmin proves that the query is good and returns results (so the data must be good too).  I then copied and pasted it into my PHP, changing only the LIKE parameter.  I think my first piece of code proves that the bindValue and use of :id in the LIKE is okay.  I know this is going to be a stupid mistake on my part but I can't find it.